# Why row and column eliminated if variable is zero in matrix operations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

could you help me to figure out why the row 1 & 2 are eliminated in here:

$  \begin{Bmatrix}
    F_1 \\
    F_2 \\
    F_3 \\
    F_4 \\
    \end{Bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    k & -k & k &-k\\
    -k & k & -k &k\\
    k & -k & k &-k\\
    -k & k & -k &k\\
    \end{bmatrix} * \begin{Bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    u_3 \\
    u_4 \\
    \end{Bmatrix}$
(Assuming k is some scalar)

Since the $u_1=0$ and $u_2=0$ the rows 1 & 2 and columns 1 &2 are eliminated. I understand why the columns 1 and 2 are gone. Since the variable $u_1$ and $u_2$ are zeros the algebraic form is:

$0k-0k+u_3k-u_4k=F_1$

$-0k+0k-u_3k+u_4k=F_2$

$0k-0k+u_3k-u_4k=F_3$

$-0k+0k-u_3k+u_4k=F_4$

But I don't understand why the prof crosses out the rows 1 and 2 as well.

P.s. any edits are welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Which** rows 1 and 2 are crossed out?  The LHS?  First factor on the RHS?  Second factor on the RHS?  More than one of these?

Comment: uhm, all. row 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is some matrix operation here that I'm missing out on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not totally clear on your question but here's an attempt.

First, deleting the first two columns of the matrix with $k$s gives
$$\begin{Bmatrix} F_1 \\ F_2 \\ F_3 \\ F_4 \\ \end{Bmatrix}
  =\begin{bmatrix} k &-k\\ -k &k\\ k &-k\\ -k &k\\ \end{bmatrix}
   * \begin{Bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ u_3 \\ u_4 \\ \end{Bmatrix}\ .$$
This doesn't work as the sizes of the matrices on the RHS don't match ($4\times2$ times $4\times1$).  You can fix this by deleting the first two rows of the $\bf u$ vector,
$$\begin{Bmatrix} F_1 \\ F_2 \\ F_3 \\ F_4 \\ \end{Bmatrix}
  =\begin{bmatrix} k &-k\\ -k &k\\ k &-k\\ -k &k\\ \end{bmatrix}
   * \begin{Bmatrix}u_3 \\ u_4 \\ \end{Bmatrix}\ ,$$
and this doesn't change anything important as you have merely stopped adding some zeros.  Now if I understood your comment correctly, you have also deleted the first two rows in other matrices,
$$\begin{Bmatrix} F_3 \\ F_4 \\ \end{Bmatrix}
  =\begin{bmatrix} k &-k\\ -k &k\\ \end{bmatrix}
   * \begin{Bmatrix}u_3 \\ u_4 \\ \end{Bmatrix}\ .$$
This gives you exactly the same information regarding $F_3$ and $F_4$, but you have lost the information about $F_1$ and $F_2$.

As to why... the only guess I can make is that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are irrelevant to the problem you are discussing, perhaps because they are in fact equal to $F_3$ and $F_4$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
F1 and F2 are in fact what we are looking for. And F3 and F4 are usually known. So when we get this new 2X2 matricies then we can find the u3 and u4.
And then! Here is a kicker. Then we revive the 4X4 matrix, and solve for F1 and F2. Because, now F1 & F2 are the only 2 unknowns.

So basically we dropped them, for convenience (as Prof said) and then reinstated them and solved them. 
Is this any clearer? What do you think?

Comment: Actually, I'm much more confused now.  If you look at the first and third rows of your matrix product you get$$F_1=ku_3-ku_4\ ,\quad F_3=ku_3-ku_4\ ,$$so $F_1=F_3$.  I don't understand how $F_3$ can be known and $F_1$ unknown when they are in fact the same!

Comment: You forgot to flip the sign. They may be equal (given k are the same) but opposite in sign.

Comment: No, look more carefully at the first matrix equation in your question: $F_1=F_3=-F_2=-F_4$.  So if you know one of the $F$s then you know them all.

Comment: This may be a stupid question (sorry abut that) but why are you equating the forces?
P.s. corrected the signs in the equation form.

Comment: ok. Nevermind.
So, My question is basically this: in your answer, that step of getting rid of F1 and F2, does this violate any matrices principles of operation?

Comment: As long as you do it carefully as I have indicated in my answer (in particular making sure that the sizes always match for multiplication), there is no violation of matrix algebra.  (Also re: why am I equating forces, basically because I don't understand what your professor is on about - he seems to be taking something really simple and making it complicated.)